# What's the equivalent of XInput* functions in Linux?

Tags: c++, c, linux, xinput

I'm porting an application that uses the Xbox controller to Linux. On windows, it essentially just uses `XInputGetState()` to read the state of the controller, so I'm looking for a replacement for that function on Linux.

I see that [wine hasn't implemented `XInputGetState()`](https://github.com/wine-mirror/wine/blob/9bd963065b1fb7b445d010897d5f84967eadf75b/dlls/xinput1_3/xinput1_3_main.c#L68), but at the same time there are a large number of games supporting the Xbox controller on Linux, so it's doable.

Does anyone know what library can be used to interact with an Xbox controller on Linux?

Comment: SDL is at the top of your list, GLFW or SFML also work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either:

1. use the [SDL library](https://wiki.libsdl.org/CategoryGameController)
2. use the functions in `linux/joystick.h` yourself
3. find some other library which abstracts (3) for you like [this](https://github.com/elanthis/gamepad) or the one linked by user3716731.

The (1-2) solutions are mainly `C`, but so is the XInput API, so you probably can deal with it.

I would probably go with number 1, because that approach should have the best documentation.

Comment: Didn't know SDL supports it. If it works, I agree, that would be the best option.

Answer (score 2):

So I know its not pure C++ however there is a great addon for openFrameworks called [ofxGamePad](https://github.com/underdoeg/ofxGamepad) that is compatible with linux. I have had success using it with linux for a gamepad.

Comment: `ofxGamePad` _is_ C++. I'd have to study how it works, but it seems promising!